# Using RxJava to make Quickblox API requests

Tags: android, rx-java, quickblox

I'm trying to use the [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/) [Android SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android) combined with [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to make some chained and time-based Quickblox API calls. The API already have *async* methods. Here are two of them:

**Create a session:**

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {


            }
        });
```

**Create a Dialog (Chat Room)**

```
QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager().createDialog(qbDialog,
            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {


                }
            });
```

As you saw, every API call must have a **Callback Implementation** as method parameter. The problem is that I have to make some chained API calls. Example:

1. Create empty session, then
2. Sign in, then
3. Retrieve user info, then
4. Login to chat service, then
5. ....

I searched a little bit about RxJava and I saw that it's good to solve this kind of problem, because you can apply some filters and other things before make the next API call. The problem is that I don't know how to adapt this API to work with RxJava.

- Should the API call with callbacks be inside the `Observable` `call()` method?
- Should the `onError()` and the `onSuccess()` methods of the Quickblox API call the `onError()` and the `onNext()`/`onCompleted()`  methods of the `Subscriber`?

Could anyone make some example of the use of 
   RxJava to create a session and then create a dialog using the
   provided **create session** and **create dialog**  API methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a example of how to create observables using `Observable.create()` in your case:

```java
Observable<QBSession> connectionObservable = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<QBSession>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super QBSession> subscriber) {
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
                    subscriber.onNext(session);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    subscriber.onError(/*some throwable here*/);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

Observable<QBDialog> dialogCreationObservable = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<QBDialog>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super QBDialog> subscriber) {
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager().createDialog(qbDialog,
                    new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                            subscriber.onNext(dialog);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                            subscriber.onError(/*some throwable here*/);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Android777 ! In this case, if I want to chain the calls should I combine the observables using flatMap?

Comment: @regmoraes yes, something like this: `connectionObservable.flatMap((Func1<QBSession, Observable<QBDialog>>) qbSession -> dialogCreationObservable);`